# Magento 2 how to get all shipping rates from CartTotalRepository

Tags: php, magento, magento2, shopping-cart

We already have table rate shipping where in US shipping will be $13, Alaska and outside of US will be $38.  On top of it we want to have rush shipping addition of $25.
I was be able to add custom shipping by follow https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/howdoi/checkout/checkout-add-custom-carrier.html.  But the issue is within rush shipping.  For the view/edit cart and step 1 of proceed to checkout I was be able to calculate rush shipping $13+$25 = $38.  But on the last step it keep show $25 rush shipping.  How can i display same $38 rush shipping on last step.  I was be able to debug to CartTotalRepository.  I put in this line hoping i can fetch all the shipping methods

[image]

```php
$rates = $address->collectShippingRates()->getGroupedAllShippingRates();
```

My aim is to fetch current table rate and do the math to add on top of customshipping.  But at this step it only yield 1 shipping method custom shipping.

Please help